# RedShift SQL subquery with Inner join

Tags: sql, join, subquery, amazon-redshift

I am using AWS Redshift SQL. I want to inner join a sub-query which has group by and inner join inside of it. When I do an outside join; I am getting an error that column does not exist.

Query:

```
SELECT      si.package_weight
FROM        "packageproduct" ub "clearpathpin"  cp ON ub.cpipr_number = cp.pin_number
  INNER JOIN "clearpathpin"  cp ON ub.cpipr_number = cp.pin_number
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT sf."AWB", SUM(up."weight") AS package_weight
    FROM "productweight" up ON up."product_id" = sf."item_id"
    GROUP BY sf."AWB"
    HAVING sf."AWB" IS NOT NULL
    ) AS si ON si.item_id = ub.order_item_id 
LIMIT 100;
```

Result:

```
ERROR: column si.item_id does not exist
```

Comment: Edit your question and include the query as *text* not an *image*.

Comment: `FROM "productweight" up ON up."product_id" = sf."item_id"` is missing a `JOIN`

Comment: did not copy right

Comment: what is "sf."??

Comment: @AlmoUbuy: Please accept the answer below if it serves what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply because `column si.item_id does not exist`

Include `item_id` in the select statement for the table `productweight`

and it should work.

Comment: I am trying to aggregate the weights that are in an air way bill package. The air way bill package may have more than one items. This is the original reason I did not include item_id because I do not want it in the group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with this query.

For your subquery, you have an `ON` statement, but it is not joining:

```
FROM "productweight" up ON up."product_id" = sf."item_id"
```

When you join the results of this subquery, you are referencing a field that does not exist within the subquery:

```
    SELECT sf."AWB", SUM(up."weight") AS package_weight
     ...
    ) AS si ON si.item_id = ub.order_item_id
```

You should imagine the subquery as creating a new, separate, briefly-existing table.  The outer query than joins that *temporary* table to the rest of the query.  So anything not explicitly resulted in the subquery will not be available to the outer query.

I would recommend when developing you write and run the subquery on its own first.  Only after it returns the results you expect (no errors, appropriate columns, etc) then you can copy/paste it in as a subquery and start developing the main query.